# Can I connect laptop to external screen with lid closed

Tags: laptop, hdmi, dell-vostro

I have a Dell laptop but the screen is 14" which is sometimes small when I work with multiple CAD files etc. I am thinking of buying a 27" 4K TV to connect to as an external screen via the HDMI port on the laptop.

However, I'm wondering if I will have to keep the laptop screen open (which surely works) but is added clutter on my relatively modest sized desk.

Or is there a way to get the laptop to keep running with lid closed and still route the display signal out via the HDMI port.

I can be using a external keyboard as well which is more comfortable.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to use is a docking station. Everything plugs in to the dock and the dock has its own power button. One cable connects the dock to the laptop. When you leave, you simply unplug one cable and take your laptop with you. When you return, plug in the dock with the screen closed and push the power button on the dock and the system will turn on using the monitor only.

You can also disable “lid close” settings in power management if you don’t want to get a dock. By choosing to not do anything when you close the lid on your laptop, you can close it while the laptop is on so just the external monitor continues to operate. Just remember that closing the lid does not put the laptop in to sleep or hibernate now. So, you’ll need to take an extra step before packing the laptop up to travel and put it in to sleep or hibernate. My preferred setting is to set the power switch to hibernate the laptop, and a quick push of the power button will prepare it for travel.